# Call to a member function beginTransaction() on a non-object when deployed to live

Tags: model, fatal-error

On my laptop everything works fine but when I deploy to our live test server I get:

`Fatal error: Call to a member function beginTransaction() on a non-object in /var/www/html/magento82/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Abstract.php on line 313`

It seems to be happening when I call:

```
//this works fine
$scan = Mage::getModel('company_returnscans/scan');
...
//the error is here
$scan->save();
```

Here's my config.xml:

```
<global>
    <models>
        <company_returnscans>
            <class>Company_ReturnScans_Model</class>
            <resourceModel>company_returnscans_resource</resourceModel>
        </company_returnscans>

        <company_returnscans_resource>
            <class>Company_ReturnScans_Model_Resource</class>
            <entities>
                <scan>
                    <table>return_scan</table>
                </scan>
            </entities>
        </company_returnscans_resource>
    </models>
</global>
```

And I'm using this class:

```
class Company_ReturnScans_Model_Scan extends Mage_Core_Model_Abstract
{
    protected function _construct()
    {
        $this->_init('company_returnscans/scan');
    }
}
```

this class:

```
class Company_ReturnScans_Model_Resource_Scan extends Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Db_Abstract
{
    protected function _construct()
    {
        $this->_init('compnay_returnscans/scan', 'scan_id');
    }
}
```

and this class:

```
class Company_ReturnScans_Model_Resource_Scan_Collection extends Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Db_Collection_Abstract
{
    protected function _construct()
    {
        $this->_init('compnay_returnscans/scan');
    }
}
```

Comment: please see my answer, if have any issue let me know.

Comment: Hello @Ryan,  Did you get a chance to look at my answer!

Answer (score 0):

There is typo in your  class name:

$this->_init('compnay_returnscans/scan', 'scan_id'); should be

> $this->_init('company_returnscans/scan', 'scan_id');

**And**

$this->_init('compnay_returnscans/scan'); Should be:

> $this->_init('company_returnscans/scan');

Please check spelling of **company**, you have written **compnay**